# 2D Registration of two shapes

Tags: c#, 2d

I am having a task to implement a way of registration of two 2D Shapes.
The first shape is the source, meaning it will never change, and the target shape is the shape that must be always aligned/registered on the source shape. For both shapes I have the X,Y coordinates.

In order to understand the problem, I'm adding a photo that explains it.

[image: Blue is the Source Shape, Red is the Target Shape]

The Angle of the rotation of Red shape is unknown and cannot be for every random red shape the same. So I need an algorithm to find the best rotation in order to match the blue shape.

Any ideas??
I've read about ICP but does it work for 2D problems? Because I used an implementation but for the 2D data it never converged, but for 3D data I found was working perfectly.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you looked at the [Generalised Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_Hough_transform)?

Comment: I have for both shapes the X,Y coordinates, does this help on GHT?

Comment: I see no reason why ICP should not work for 2D data, but it may depend on your specific implementation. There seem to be many variants

Comment: The transform operates primarily on 2D arrays of bits (i.e. black & white images). If you can rasterize your shapes into a 2D array of bits it should work.

Comment: Maybe the ICP implementation was settling on a local minimum and could not converge to the final solution.